# WPF, display attribute value in TreeView instead of node name

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, xpath

If I have the following data template for a `TreeView`, what do I need to change so that each `TreeViewItem` shows the value of the `name` attribute on each XML node, instead of the node name?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding XPath="child::node()" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Text">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neeeeever mind, just had to replace `Path=Name` and `Path=Value` with `XPath=@name` in the two `Setter`s.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your binding with this:

```
<Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Attributes[Name].Value}" />
```

Found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238196/how-to-bind-xml-attribute-to-treeview-nodes-while-databinding-xdocument-to-wpf-t/238282#238282).